# MariaDB Galera Cluster is not syncing

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, galera

I have deployed MariaDB Cluster before, and this problem only comes out recently (I don't have this problem before and I don't know why).

I have server 1, 2 and 3. I executed an INSERT command at server 3, however, the tables at server 1 and 2 remains unchanged.

3 servers are at different parts of the world. `After the INSERT command, the state uuid remains the same`.

Here is the status of server 1:

`MariaDB [mysql]> show status like 'wsrep_%';
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                                                    |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_local_state_uuid       | c4f9e2e2-fee1-11e5-8648-a22b867b5a6e                     |
| wsrep_protocol_version       | 7                                                        |
| wsrep_last_committed         | 205                                                      |
| wsrep_replicated             | 170                                                      |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes       | 160481                                                   |
| wsrep_repl_keys              | 664                                                      |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes        | 9222                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes        | 140379                                                   |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes       | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_received               | 46                                                       |
| wsrep_received_bytes         | 26150                                                    |
| wsrep_local_commits          | 170                                                      |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures    | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_replays          | 1                                                        |
| wsrep_local_send_queue       | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_max   | 1                                                        |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_min   | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg   | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue       | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_max   | 1                                                        |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_min   | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg   | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto    | 1                                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused    | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent      | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv      | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance     | 7.482927                                                 |
| wsrep_apply_oooe             | 0.009756                                                 |
| wsrep_apply_oool             | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_apply_window           | 1.009756                                                 |
| wsrep_commit_oooe            | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_commit_oool            | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_commit_window          | 1.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_local_state            | 4                                                        |
| wsrep_local_state_comment    | Synced                                                   |
| wsrep_cert_index_size        | 28                                                       |
| wsrep_causal_reads           | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_cert_interval          | 0.009756                                                 |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses     | server1:3306,server2:3306,server3:3306 |
| wsrep_evs_delayed            |                                                          |
| wsrep_evs_evict_list         |                                                          |
| wsrep_evs_repl_latency       | 0.200155/0.201113/0.201752/0.000614937/4                 |
| wsrep_evs_state              | OPERATIONAL                                              |
| wsrep_gcomm_uuid             | c4f91b4f-fee1-11e5-8c4f-6e451c332f79                     |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id        | 3                                                        |
| wsrep_cluster_size           | 3                                                        |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid     | c4f9e2e2-fee1-11e5-8648-a22b867b5a6e                     |
| wsrep_cluster_status         | Primary                                                  |
| wsrep_connected              | ON                                                       |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts        | 6                                                        |
| wsrep_local_index            | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_provider_name          | Galera                                                   |
| wsrep_provider_vendor        | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>                        |
| wsrep_provider_version       | 25.3.14(r3560)                                           |
| wsrep_ready                  | ON                                                       |
| wsrep_thread_count           | 2                                                        |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+`

Status of server 2:

`MariaDB [(none)]> show status like 'wsrep_%';
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                                                    |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_local_state_uuid       | c4f9e2e2-fee1-11e5-8648-a22b867b5a6e                     |
| wsrep_protocol_version       | 7                                                        |
| wsrep_last_committed         | 225                                                      |
| wsrep_replicated             | 35                                                       |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes       | 25700                                                    |
| wsrep_repl_keys              | 119                                                      |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes        | 1757                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes        | 21703                                                    |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes       | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_received               | 187                                                      |
| wsrep_received_bytes         | 177793                                                   |
| wsrep_local_commits          | 35                                                       |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures    | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_replays          | 1                                                        |
| wsrep_local_send_queue       | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_max   | 1                                                        |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_min   | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg   | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue       | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_max   | 4                                                        |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_min   | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg   | 0.032086                                                 |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto    | 9                                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused    | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent      | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv      | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance     | 7.193548                                                 |
| wsrep_apply_oooe             | 0.004630                                                 |
| wsrep_apply_oool             | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_apply_window           | 1.004630                                                 |
| wsrep_commit_oooe            | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_commit_oool            | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_commit_window          | 1.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_local_state            | 4                                                        |
| wsrep_local_state_comment    | Synced                                                   |
| wsrep_cert_index_size        | 28                                                       |
| wsrep_causal_reads           | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_cert_interval          | 0.009217                                                 |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses     | server1:3306,server2:3306,server3:3306 |
| wsrep_evs_delayed            |                                                          |
| wsrep_evs_evict_list         |                                                          |
| wsrep_evs_repl_latency       | 0.200138/0.201917/0.203696/0.00177914/2                  |
| wsrep_evs_state              | OPERATIONAL                                              |
| wsrep_gcomm_uuid             | d562e272-fee1-11e5-b2a2-d3a6b5579aab                     |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id        | 3                                                        |
| wsrep_cluster_size           | 3                                                        |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid     | c4f9e2e2-fee1-11e5-8648-a22b867b5a6e                     |
| wsrep_cluster_status         | Primary                                                  |
| wsrep_connected              | ON                                                       |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts        | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_index            | 1                                                        |
| wsrep_provider_name          | Galera                                                   |
| wsrep_provider_vendor        | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>                        |
| wsrep_provider_version       | 25.3.14(r3560)                                           |
| wsrep_ready                  | ON                                                       |
| wsrep_thread_count           | 2                                                        |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
57 rows in set (0.01 sec)`

Status of server3 (As you can see, the latency shows all 0 but I don't know why)

`MariaDB [(none)]> show status like 'wsrep_%';
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                                                    |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_local_state_uuid       | c4f9e2e2-fee1-11e5-8648-a22b867b5a6e                     |
| wsrep_protocol_version       | 7                                                        |
| wsrep_last_committed         | 245                                                      |
| wsrep_replicated             | 5                                                        |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes       | 4350                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_keys              | 11                                                       |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes        | 203                                                      |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes        | 3827                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes       | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_received               | 226                                                      |
| wsrep_received_bytes         | 208559                                                   |
| wsrep_local_commits          | 1                                                        |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures    | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_replays          | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_send_queue       | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_max   | 1                                                        |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_min   | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg   | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue       | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_max   | 1                                                        |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_min   | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg   | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto    | 19                                                       |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused    | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent      | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv      | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance     | 7.022026                                                 |
| wsrep_apply_oooe             | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_apply_oool             | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_apply_window           | 1.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_commit_oooe            | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_commit_oool            | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_commit_window          | 1.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_local_state            | 4                                                        |
| wsrep_local_state_comment    | Synced                                                   |
| wsrep_cert_index_size        | 28                                                       |
| wsrep_causal_reads           | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_cert_interval          | 0.008811                                                 |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses     | server1:3306,server2:3306,server3:3306 |
| wsrep_evs_delayed            |                                                          |
| wsrep_evs_evict_list         |                                                          |
| wsrep_evs_repl_latency       | 0/0/0/0/0                                                |
| wsrep_evs_state              | OPERATIONAL                                              |
| wsrep_gcomm_uuid             | fd022144-fee1-11e5-a7a3-f23274fef9c3                     |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id        | 3                                                        |
| wsrep_cluster_size           | 3                                                        |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid     | c4f9e2e2-fee1-11e5-8648-a22b867b5a6e                     |
| wsrep_cluster_status         | Primary                                                  |
| wsrep_connected              | ON                                                       |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts        | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_index            | 2                                                        |
| wsrep_provider_name          | Galera                                                   |
| wsrep_provider_vendor        | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>                        |
| wsrep_provider_version       | 25.3.14(r3560)                                           |
| wsrep_ready                  | ON                                                       |
| wsrep_thread_count           | 2                                                        |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
57 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

iptables at all three servers are set to ACCEPT all input and output traffics.

The log shows that all servers have joined and synced with the cluster.

Does anyone know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found that is is the app's problem that use MyISAM as storage engine, which causes the error. There is no error after change back to InnoDB.

Comment: As MyISAM storage engine is non-transactional, it is not supported in Galera. FWIW, changes in MySQL tables can still be replicated to other nodes by turning on wsrep_replicate_myisam. But, this feature is experimental.

Comment: consider forcing customers to use InnoDB engine. See  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#enforce_storage_engine `SET GLOBAL enforce_storage_engine=InnoDB;`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check the table engines, Because the Galera cluster support InnoDB engine not MyISAM.

So here is a easy way how to migrate Mysql database with MyISAM tables into Galera and InnoDB:

1. Make sure your db schema doesn't contain FULLTEXT indexes or any other constructions, which are not supported by InnoDB engine
2. Dump schema of your database
3. replace in the dump string "MYISAM" with "INNODB"
4. Dump data
5. Prepare db user in Galera Cluster (mysql.user table is not replicated across cluster, so you have to insert db user into each of your mariadb servers)
6. Import schema (with innodb engine)
7. Import data
8. Cleanup dump files

Thanks from https://support.qualityunit.com/718375-Migrate-MySQL-Database-with-Myisam-engine-to-MariaDB-Galera-Cluster